# Slim Framework routing not working

Tags: php, apache, slim

I'm learning Slim Framework and got stuck with its routing.

**Working Code. Code snippet #1:**

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get("/", function () {
   echo "Hello SlimFramework";
});

$app->run();
```

**Not Working. Code snippet #2:**

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get("/hello/{name}", function (Request $request, Response $response) {

     $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
     $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

     return $response; 
});

$app->run();
```

I'm getting "Not Found
The requested URL /hello/name was not found on this server." for Code snippet #2. Any clue what's going on here ?

**.htaccess File**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sounds like your `.htaccess` isn't having the proper effect. Best way to check that is to break it - if you add `Test` to the top of it and your site doesn't break, it's not being read.

Comment: May be a silly question but are you running the app via Apache? If so, is the document root of the server or virtual-host set to the app's `public` directory? Is the `.htaccess` file `public/.htaccess`?

Comment: give this line a try in .htaccess file `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: @ceejayoz 's solution helped me identify the issue. My .htaccess was not being read.

Comment: @bianca please add your solution here as an answer. It's highly likely others may face the same problem and there's nothing worse than finding your problem online with a _"never mind, I solved it"_ comment

Comment: @Phil This is exactly what just happened to me...ok bianca your htaccess wasn't being read...so then what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start with clean slate in order to solve this issue for me. @ceejayoz's solution about making sure if .htaccess is working correctly, was a great help to test .htaccess configuration.